# OsX + Ubuntu SSD and HD separate/home?

Tags: 14.04, home-directory

I have an iMac 21,5" 2011 and I'm going to upgrade it installing a 250GB Ssd

I was wondering what it's the best configuration for a dual boot OS X + Ubuntu.

Option 1
Ssd: 150Gb for OS X 
     100GB for Ubuntu 
HD: 1 TB hfs+ and add it in the fstab of Ubuntu to mount the HD at boot.

Option 2
Separate/home and put it in the HD

Comment: Option 1 is good, any reason to put the /home on another drive ? 100GB is plenty of space for Ubuntu if you keep media on a separate HDD.

Comment: I've added the HD to the fstab in Ubuntu but I can't write in this disk. This is what I've added in the fstab: /dev/sda3 /media/sda3 hfsplus defaults 0 0?

Comment: You forgot to add some permissions, try this line `/dev/sda3 /media/sda3 hfsplus rw, user, umask=003, exec 0 0`. I think (but am no expert) the `defaults` option, gave ownership to root, now your user can read, write and execute this drive.

Comment: Thanks but it still says: owner=root and I can't write in the disk

Comment: How about this `/dev/sda3 /media/sda3 hfsplus rw,  exec, umask=003, uid=1000,gid=1000` Check your `uid` and `gid` by running `id -u` as your user, no root

Comment: I must point out (though I may be wrong) the name of your disk, i have only ever see it written as uuid not /dev/sda3, like this `UUID=22624673247 /media/sda3 hfsplus.....` It may be nothing but you can find your uuid with `sudo blkid`

Comment: it does't matter, on other computer i have the swap partition like this: /dev/sdxx / none swap ....    and it works fine. If you have two distros of linux in the same computer using the same swap partition it's better than ussing UUID because it can be a conflict.

Comment: by the way. /dev/sda3 /media/sda3 hfsplus rw, exec, umask=003, uid=1000,gid=1000 dindn't work neither

Comment: I have just tried It ... Just in case but it doesn't work with the udid

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

Here it's what i've done:

1. Boot Mac osX,open a terminal and disable journaling of the partition you want to include in the fstab, in my case: diskutil disableJournal /dev/disk1s2
2. Boot Linux, open a terminal and change fstab with nano /etc/fstab
   include (in my case) at the botoom: /dev/sda2 /media/Macintosh_HD hfsplus rw,exec,auto,users 0 0